# Getting the frame from a bounding rectangle of UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, frame, uibezierpath, bounds

I am using a `UIBezierPath` to create shapes which I display using a `CAShapeLayer`. However, in order to set the correct frame of the `CAShapeLayer` I need the frame that contains the `UIBeziehPath` object. 
According to the documentation there is the `bounds` property. Yet, when I use it the layer doesn't contain the drawn path. Is there a way to convert the `path.bounds` to a `CGRect` corresponding to the correct frame in the containing view's coordinate system? I have tried

```
[self convertRect:path.bounds toView:self]
```

without success.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
let pathRect = shapeLayer.path!.boundingBoxOfPath
```

Also, from the [CALayer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/frame):

> The frame rectangle is position and size of the layer specified in the superlayer’s coordinate space. For layers, the frame rectangle is a computed property that is derived from the values in thebounds, anchorPoint and position properties. When you assign a new value to this property, the layer changes its position and bounds properties to match the rectangle you specified. The values of each coordinate in the rectangle are measured in points.

You can set the bounds (which leaves the layer position untouched) or set the frame (which will be converted to bounds & position).